# Connecting to a new LDAP Server in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ldap

I inherited an internal Rails 2 app, which I just try to keep working for the time being, as I'm not very Rails proficient.  It does user authentication using net/ldap.  This week, our LDAP server has been moved from a Linux machine to a Windows one.  Now authentication fails for everyone.

I have 2 variables:  ***username*** is the user's network ID, and ***password*** is the password s/he entered.  Here's the code:

```
ldap = Net::LDAP.new
ldap.host = 'new_server.mycompany.org'
ldap.auth 'cn=' + username + ',ou=active,ou=employees,ou=users,o=mycompany', password
attrs = ["sn", "givenname", "commonname", "workforceid"]
filter = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( "cn", username )
if ldap.bind
  ldap.search( :base => 'ou=active,ou=employees,ou=users,o=mycompany', :filter => filter, :attributes => attrs, :return_result => false ) do |entry|
    if User.find_by_login(entry["commonname"], :conditions => ["is_deleted = 0"]) != nil
      session[:user_id] = entry["givenname"].to_s.capitalize + " " + entry["sn"].to_s.capitalize
      session[:login] = entry["commonname"].to_s
      session[:staff_id] = entry["workforceid"].to_s
      return true
    else
      flash[:notice] = "User does not have the proper rights to use this application"
      return false
    end
  end
  return true
else
  flash[:notice] = ldap.get_operation_result.code.to_s + ' - ' + ldap.get_operation_result.message
  return false
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Fails how? Error messages? Anything? Please read [mcve].

Comment: It fails on the ldap.bind statement, going to the last else clause.

Comment: And what's the error (i.e. `ldap.get_operation_result` output)?